# How can I create a continuous animation with a image in iOS

Tags: ios, animation, uiimageview, uiimage, progress-bar

How can I create a continuous animation with an image in iOS?
i want to create a looping action where an imageView of mine stays within the screen boundaries but the x axis constantly forward so it would basically generate a animation effect.. so i have to use only one image. any help would be greatly appreciated!! ideas?

my image is a large one in 800*12 pixels .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `animationImages` property of [UIImageView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImageView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to animate the frames of your animation:

```
UIImageView *view = // etc.

UIImage *frame1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"];
UIImage *frame2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"2.png"];
// etc.

view.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:frame1, frame2, ..., nil];

view.animationDuration = 1.0;
view.animationRepeatCount = 0;

[view startAnimating];
```

Comment: thanks for this , but how can i do using one image by setting its x position.. using any other way without this imageview animation ...